# Python issue with pycurl and openssl

Tags: python, openssl, pycurl

I am trying to run code that uses pycurl but when I do i get the following error:

```
uilleann-pipes-160:data_collection Jim$ python xlsxDownloader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "xlsxDownloader.py", line 21, in <module>
  from import_hedgehogs import Link
 File "/Users/Jim/Documents/Hedgehogs/hedgehogs/data_collection/import_hedgehogs.py", line 8, in <module>
 import pycurl
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)
```

When I do "which pycurl" in terminal it gives no output so I then tried installing pycurl using "pip install pycurl". However, When I do that I get the following error:

```
uilleann-pipes-160:data_collection Jim$ pip install pycurl
Collecting pycurl
 Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycurl
 Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/zw/hmv25ltn4hxcr3t9lrx7fc9r0000gn/T/pip-build-gqCefl/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zw/hmv25ltn4hxcr3t9lrx7fc9r0000gn/T/pip-Vbtxf4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.54.0)
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/curl
copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/curl
running build_ext
building 'pycurl' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/src
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.1" -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/src/docstrings.o

In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
src/pycurl.h:164:13: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#   include <openssl/ssl.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
 ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/zw/hmv25ltn4hxcr3t9lrx7fc9r0000gn/T/pip-build-gqCefl/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zw/hmv25ltn4hxcr3t9lrx7fc9r0000gn/T/pip-Vbtxf4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zw/hmv25ltn4hxcr3t9lrx7fc9r0000gn/T/pip-build-gqCefl/pycurl/
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the error messages into the question rather than including a screenshot.

Comment: Is that edit better or should I still copy and paste instead?

Comment: Agree with @ZiyadEdher. Please, can you include logs.

Comment: I copy and pasted the error messages in. I was not sure of the best way to break up the really long lines

Comment: @JimHines Try this move https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/530#issuecomment-395403253

Answer (score 0):

Install the first two packages

1. `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`
2. `python -m pip install pybind11`

*These are optional*

1. `sudo apt install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev`
2. `sudo apt install libssl-dev`
3. `sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev`